# WebHook и Telegram API

Tags: node.js, запрос, telegram, telegraf, webhook

Писал до этого ботов для платформы телеграмм на языке Node.js и библиотеке Telegraf, доступной в NPM'e.

С недавнего времени решил написать свою простенькую библиотеку, что бы использовать "свое", а не "чье-то". Начал читать про WebHook'и. Нашел в оффициальной документации телеграмма API метод `setWebhook`. Нужный аргумент - URL, куда будет Telegram отправлять запросы о новых событиях.

Я всегда мог запустить своего бота не с хостинга, а с ПК. Так вот вопрос, какой URL нужно посылать, чтобы мне на мой ПК приходили уведомления о новых собитиях? (Это даже звучит для меня странно)

Answer (score 0):

Для получения информации о новых событиях в библиотеке Telegraf поумолчинию используется метод из документации телеграмма [getUpdates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates).

Использование вебхуков ([setWebhook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook)) имеет преимущества, но предназначено всё-таки для серверов. (Хотя и на персональный ПК натянуть можно, если иметь выделенный "Белый" IP)